# automatic 301 redirect to parent category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

We are scheduling posts to be archived on a monthly basis. However, this is causing a large amount of 404 errors on the website and obvious SEO issues.

All our posts sit inside a category. So my question is, how do we create an automated 301 redirect when a post is archived (unpublished) to it's parent category?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a plugin called [Auto Redirect 404 in 301 for Trashed Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-redirect-404/) which I think is what you're looking for. It will automatically redirect requests for deleted posts.

> This plugin allows you to automatically produce 301 redirects to the home page or another URL for deleted posts and taxonomies to avoid 404 errors.

Comment: Thanks for this plugin. I've just tested it. It seems to do half the job though. We have multiple categories, so lets say we have a fashion post - it needs to be redirected to the fashion category. Likewise for an 'entertainment' post, it needs to redirect to the 'entertainment' category.
Maybe I wasn't 100% clear in my original question :)

Comment: @purse9644 the plugin is probably the closest thing to do what you want without writing custom code, which you can just modify the plugin if you had to, instead of writing something from scratch